# passed parameter not working on xpath, although working in unit test

Tags: php, oop, xpath, simplexml

```
class ad_xml_model extends \ITico_core\common_class {

    public function get_info_from_ad($input_id) {
        $xml_file = parent::get_set('xml');
        $ad_info = $xml_file->xpath("//ad[@id='" . $input_id . "']");
        parent::get_set('ad_info', $ad_info);
        return $ad_info;
    }

}
```

The above code works when unit testing it, i've tried passing both a string and a int into the function and it works both times.

```
<h2>get_info_from_ad</h2>
test data: 1<br>
info from ad:- <br>
<?php
$ad_xml_model->get_info_from_ad(1);
$ad_info = $ad_xml_model->get_set('ad_info');
print_r($ad_info);
```

but in the code below when being called from the controller its not working

```
class main_controller(){
    $ad_top_limit = count($ads_from_category);
    $key = rand(0, $ad_top_limit - 1);
    $chosen_ad = $ads_from_category[$key];
    parent::get_set('chosen_ad', $chosen_ad);
    $ad_info = $ad_xml_model->get_info_from_ad($chosen_ad);
    parent::get_set('ad_info', $ad_info);
    if ($ad_info != null) {
        switch ($ad_type) {
            case NUll:
                break;
            case 'long':
                $long_view = new long_view($ad_info);
                $long_view->show_ad();
        }
    }
}
```

and the debug page testing

```
<?php
echo $main_controller->get_set('chosen_ad') . "<br>";
?>
ad information:-: <br>
<?php
print_r($main_controller->get_set('ad_info'));
```

[screenshot of the debug page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZpfv.png)

I've went every step of the way echoing all the variables to check that they aren't null but for some reason the xpath just doesnt work when being called from the main controller but it works fine from the unit test even though the exact same parameters are being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution was to implicitly tell the xpath it was an int

```
public function get_info_from_ad($input_id) {
    $xml_file = parent::get_set('xml');
    $ad_info = $xml_file->xpath("//ad[@id='" . (int)$input_id . "']");
    parent::get_set('ad_info', $ad_info);
    return $ad_info;
}
```

for some reason if I set it to a string it still doesn't work, perhaps someone else could share light on this.